# Auto reply to email address contained within message body

Tags: gmail

Infusionsoft sends my company email referrals using the same template each time with the same subject line. Unfortunately an auto-response would go to the Infusionsoft email, *not* the person who submitted the form. The person's email is contained within the body of the message.

I want to setup a script or something that will autorespond to that email. They all have the same subject line so that filter part is easy.

Any help is appreciated. I am using Gmail but I could use Thunderbird if necessary to make this work and just pull the emails into Thunderbird. Prefer to stay in Gmail if possible.

```
From: <noreply@infusionsoft.com>
Date: Thu, May 25, 2017 at 5:34 PM
Subject: 6 Week Challenge Application Complete
To: PeoriaFD@thecamptc.com


A web form (*Peoria Challenge*) was filled out at:
http://www.thecamptc.com/transformation/peoria/challenge/

*The following information was provided:*

BrowserLanguage en-us
First Name Mitch
Email xxx@cox.net
Mobile Number 6022957540<(602)%295-9958>

IP Address 
Referring Referral Partner

--001a113729b0b37778055062c7d0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr"><br><div class=3D"gmail_quote">---------- Forwarded messag=
e ----------<br>From: <b class=3D"gmail_sendername"></b> <span dir=3D"ltr">=
&lt;<a href=3D"mailto:noreply@infusionsoft.com">noreply@infusionsoft.com</a=
>&gt;</span><br>Date: Thu, May 25, 2017 at 5:34 PM<br>Subject: 6 Week Chall=
enge Application Complete<br>To: <a href=3D"mailto:PeoriaFD@thecamptc.com">=
PeoriaFD@thecamptc.com</a><br><br><br><u></u>


<div>
<div id=3D"m_-641795700154948530mainContent" style=3D"text-align:left">
<table cellpadding=3D"10" cellspacing=3D"0" style=3D"background-color:rgb(2=
25,225,225);width:100%;height:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign=3D"top">
<table align=3D"center" cellspacing=3D"0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" style=3D"width:600px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style=3D"background-color:rgb(255,255,255);text-align:left;margin:0;pad=
ding:0;border:none;white-space:normal;line-height:normal;height:30px">
<div>
<div>
<img src=3D"https://ww284.infusionsoft.com/slices/branding/infusion_logo.pn=
g?b=3D1.65.0.65" style=3D"margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;wh=
ite-space:normal;line-height:normal">
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF" cellpadding=3D"20" cellspacing=3D"0" style=3D"wi=
dth:600px;background-color:rgb(255,255,255)">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style=3D"text-align:left;margin:0;padding:20px;border:none;white-space:=
normal;line-height:normal" valign=3D"top"><span class=3D"">
<div>
<div style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0=
;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-space:normal;line-height:norma=
l;overflow:visible">
A web form (<strong>Peoria Challenge</strong>) was filled out at:<br clear=
=3D"none">
<a href=3D"http://www.thecamptc.com/transformation/peoria/challenge/" shape=
=3D"rect" style=3D"color:rgb(11,5,169)" target=3D"_blank">http://www.thecam=
ptc.com/<wbr>transformation/peoria/<wbr>challenge/</a>
<br clear=3D"none">
<br clear=3D"none">
<strong>The following information was provided:</strong>
<br clear=3D"none">
<br clear=3D"none">
</div>
</div>
</span><div>
<div>
<table width=3D"100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px=
;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-spa=
ce:normal;line-height:normal">
BrowserLanguage
</td><td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size=
:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;whit=
e-space:normal;line-height:normal">
en-us
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px=
;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-spa=
ce:normal;line-height:normal">
First Name
</td><td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size=
:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;whit=
e-space:normal;line-height:normal">
Mitch Me
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px=
;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-spa=
ce:normal;line-height:normal">
Email
</td><td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size=
:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;whit=
e-space:normal;line-height:normal">
<a href=3D"mailto:xxx@cox.net" target=3D"_blank">xxx@cox.=
net</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px=
;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-spa=
ce:normal;line-height:normal">
Mobile Number
</td><td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size=
:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;whit=
e-space:normal;line-height:normal">
<a href=3D"tel:(623)%20707-9958" value=3D"+16237079958" target=3D"_blank">6=
237079958</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px=
;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-spa=
ce:normal;line-height:normal">
=C2=A0
</td><td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size=
:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;whit=
e-space:normal;line-height:normal">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px=
;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-spa=
ce:normal;line-height:normal">
IP Address
</td><td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size=
:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;whit=
e-space:normal;line-height:normal">
172.58.21.20
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px=
;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-spa=
ce:normal;line-height:normal">
Referring Referral Partner
</td><td colspan=3D"1" rowspan=3D"1" style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size=
:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0;padding:0;background:none;border:none;whit=
e-space:normal;line-height:normal">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div><span class=3D"">
<div>
<div style=3D"color:rgb(99,99,99);font-size:12px;font-family:arial;margin:0=
;padding:0;background:none;border:none;white-space:normal;line-height:norma=
l;overflow:visible">
<br clear=3D"none">
<a href=3D"https://ww284.infusionsoft.com/Contact/manageContact.jsp?view=3D=
edit&amp;ID=3D1326935" shape=3D"rect" style=3D"color:rgb(11,5,169)" target=
=3D"_blank">Click here</a> to view this Contact&#39;s record.
</div>
</div>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<br><br><div id=3D"m_-641795700154948530branding" style=3D"text-align:right=
;display:block"><a href=3D"https://crm.infusionsoft.com/go/infs/footer_ww28=
4/html" target=3D"_blank"><img border=3D"0" src=3D"https://infusionmedia.s3=
.amazonaws.com/app/template/delivered_white.png"></a></div></div>
</div><br></div>
```

Comment: The Gmail part of your question is on-topic here, but not the Thunderbird part. That part would be on-topic at [su], however.

Comment: I have updated as requested. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the content of these emails then you could look for a `mailto:` tag and use what comes after it as the send address.
This assumes, looking at your email body, that the following would be the address you want to send to:

```
mailto:PeoriaFD@thecamptc.com
```

Of course, I don't know if you have access to the email file. I haven't researched it in my Gmail stuff. You could automate moving the email to a folder if it meets the criteria you want and then look through everything in that folder.